# How can I send an HTML email?

Tags: html, email

How can I send email in html?
I have written code that is sent off.

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>E-mail form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="MAILTO:reciveremail@.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="100"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```